# Can't find ttyUSB in /dev after connecting my USB dongle

Tags: 12.04, usb, tty, 3g

I'm desperately trying to connect a 3G dongle to Ubuntu 12.04. Unfortunately, every time I try to connect (using wvdial) I'm met with the message `Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory` I have looked in `/dev` and there are actually no ttyUSB files in that folder.

I have tried `lsusb` command which actually does list my dongle

the output of `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1029  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 077: ID 1004:607f LG Electronics, Inc.
```

output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```
14:42:43 ubuntu kernel: [ 5320.716507] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 52
14:42:45 ubuntu kernel: [ 5322.449570] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 53 using ehci_hcd
14:42:45 ubuntu kernel: [ 5322.544073] scsi155 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
14:42:45 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 53: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
14:42:45 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 53 was not an MTP device
14:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 5323.542840] scsi 155:0:0:0: CD-ROM            LG       Autorun          1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
14:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 5323.554690] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x tray
14:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 5323.554939] sr 155:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
14:42:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 5323.555458] sr 155:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
14:42:46 ubuntu usb_modeswitch: switching device 1004:607f on 002/053
14:43:16 ubuntu kernel: [ 5353.691487] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 53
14:43:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 5354.913282] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 54 using ehci_hcd
14:43:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 5355.008311] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
14:43:17 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 54: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
14:43:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 5355.009593] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.2: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
14:43:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 5355.010501] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.4: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
14:43:18 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 54 was not an MTP device
14:43:18 ubuntu kernel: [ 5355.736283] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 54
14:43:20 ubuntu kernel: [ 5357.469454] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 55 using ehci_hcd
14:43:20 ubuntu kernel: [ 5357.564070] scsi156 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
14:43:20 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 55: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
14:43:20 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 55 was not an MTP device
14:43:21 ubuntu kernel: [ 5358.562387] scsi 156:0:0:0: CD-ROM            LG       Autorun          1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
14:43:21 ubuntu kernel: [ 5358.575263] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x tray
14:43:21 ubuntu kernel: [ 5358.575469] sr 156:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
14:43:21 ubuntu kernel: [ 5358.575609] sr 156:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
14:43:21 ubuntu usb_modeswitch: switching device 1004:607f on 002/055
```

My USB 3G dongle is the last one on this list (LG Electronics)

How do i get my dongle to show up in a ttyusb?

Answer (score 0):

read from your syslog:

- the device seems to emulate a CD drive which delivers windows drivers.
- there are ttyACM devices. Did you try /dev/ttyACM1 and 2 instead of ttyUSB0?

Comment: Hi i've tried searching using the device id... many posts on the same subject... but no actual answer. As for the kernel 'im running Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-40-generic #64-Ubuntu

Comment: Its not a phone its a USB 3G dongle. I have checked out the webpage you sent me. The first sentence says "Firstly, this is NOT the same as the LG HDM-2100 (EVDO Rev.A USB modem) which has the same device ID - the commands required are totally different" the one i have is the LG HDM 2100 so anything listed on this page wont work

Comment: output of tail -f /var/log/syslog

Comment: Yep ur absolutely right the device does deliver windows drivers as an emulated cd, as for ttyACM i have checked in the /dev folder for these but unfortunately they are also not present :(

Comment: for wlan one may use windows drivers but for G3 I fear not. Are you absolutely sure there is no ACM in dev? try `cd /dev ; find| grep ttyACM` in case it's in a subdir. if not, I cannot help any furter. if a device isn't supported by the kernel you have to write a driver yourself or find a similar device that has a driver that works for you.